# Kubernetes Crash Loop Error, container wont run and can't see logs

Tags: kubernetes

I have a working docker image which I am trying to now use on Kubernetes but as I try to run the deployment it never runs. It gets stuck in a crash loop error and I have no way of working out what the logs say because it exits so quickly. I've included my deployment yaml file to see if there is something obviously wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: newapp
  labels:
    app: newapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: newapp
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 # for versions before 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: newapp
  labels:
    app: newapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: newapp
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: newapp
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: customwebimage
        name: newapp
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: newapp-config
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: test123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view the previous logs by adding `-p`

`kubectl logs -p pod-name`

I'd delete the Deployments Pod and try this with a new Pod, which will run 5 times before entering CrashLoopBackoff.

If the error isn't happening during container runtime, then you can describe the pod to see for scheduling / instantiation errors:

`kubectl describe pod pod-name`

Comment: kubectl logs -p pod-name - this one doesn't return anything. The second one just gives me a message that the container is "Back-off restarting failed container"

Comment: UPDATE: I've managed to get more out of the describe command. So it turns out that the container is exiting with status code of '0' with completed. Anyone know how I can stop that?

Comment: @Rutnet it doesn't sound like your application is behaving as you expect. Try running that image locally without passing any commands or args to it, just let it run the command found in the Dockerfile. I expect you'll find it too exits zero.

Comment: Agree with @Zach. Are you sure your docker image has an entrypoint/CMD defined? Is it a command that will be "long-running" and not just finish really quickly?

Comment: @Guys, my CMD was not defined in the deployment file. Once I added that in - it all worked fine. Thanks